# Formatting a date in Spark dataframe leads to unexpected format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to change the format of a `processed_time` field in my DataFrame.

Originally it looks like this: `2017-05-12 11:33:50 -0700` and I want to format it to `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` `(2017-05-12 11:33:50)`

However after formating using the approach shown below the value gets a zero after seconds `2017-05-12 11:33:50.0`
I guess it relates to a timezone.
How is it possible achieve the format without zero in the end?

```
    .withColumn("processed_time",
            to_utc_timestamp(unix_timestamp(col("processed_time")).cast(TimestampType),
                    "UTC"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After transformation, the column `processed_time` on your `DataFrame` is of type `TimestampType`. Therefore, the column values are of type `java.sql.Timestamp`.

The trailing zero that you see is the number of nanoseconds (because `java.sql.Timestamp` precision allows it). It's just here because when doing `your_df.show()`, the method `toString` is called on `java.sql.Timestamp`.

If you just want to have your result formatted (but as a `String`), you can add `.cast(StringType)` when modifying your `processed_time` column :

```
df.withColumn(
    "processed_time",
    to_utc_timestamp(
        unix_timestamp(col("processed_time")).cast(TimestampType),
        "UTC"
    ).cast(StringType)
)
```

You can also use `date_format`, as written in the comments :

```
df.withColumn(
    "processed_time",
    date_format(
        to_utc_timestamp(
            unix_timestamp(col("processed_time")).cast(TimestampType),
            "UTC"
        ),
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    )
)
```

If you really need a `TimestampType`, then you can just forget about the trailing zero during your transforms, and then just use a `SimpleDateFormat` afterwards for display :

```
val firstTimestampFromDf: java.sql.Timestamp = df
    .select("processed_time")
    .head
    .getTimestamp(0)

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

val simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
val firstTimestampFromDfFormatted = simpleDateFormat.format(firstTimestampFromDf)
```

Comment: I've tried your approach but for some reason when I do `.withColumn("processed_time", to_utc_timestamp(unix_timestamp(col("processed_time")).cast(StringType), "UTC"))` there is NULL value in the column

Comment: Actually I don't really need a timestamp here. When I needed a formatted current timestamp as a StringType it was easy to achieve with `date_format`: `.withColumn("processed_time", date_format(lit(current_timestamp()), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))`

Comment: @samba I've just updated my answer with an example of `.cast(StringType)`. In your first comment, you simply did not put `.cast(StringType)` at the right place. If the answer solves your problem, don't forget to accept the answer to help other people facing similar issues.

Comment: Thank you, you've just saved our DWH.